# Trying to save image base64 into byte[] in spring boot database

Tags: java, spring-boot

https://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter website I use to convert image to base64
https://unsplash.com/photos/KaK2jp8ie8s image I am using

so using the image and website right above. I am converting this image into base64 and I am trying to save it into my spring boot h2 database. It won't let me saying it is not a byte[]. How could I do it?

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Data
public class Fromage implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String nom;
    private double prix;
    private int vieillese;
    private int quantite;

    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    public Fromage(){}

    public Fromage(String nom, double prix, int vieillese, int quantite, byte[] data) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.vieillese = vieillese;
        this.quantite = quantite;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```
        byte[] bob = {1,2,3};
        Fromage fromage = new Fromage("Chevre",50.15,10,1,bob);
        fromageRepository.save(fromage);
```

trying to do this but replace bob with image base64 string